SElinux policy not allowing avc media type
encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC);

Here I am trying to call the AVC encoder, but I am having the following error:
2024-09-02 18:47:21.879   718-718   SELinux                 hwservicemanager                         
E  avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.oplus.hardware.performance::IPerformance 
sid=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c160,c256,c512,c768 pid=20884 
scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c160,c256,c512,c768 
tcontext=u:object_r:hal_performance_hwservice:s0 
tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=0

I want to avoid changing the SEPolicy, is there a way around so that it works on any device,i can see untrusted app is it only functional for system apps?
Thanks.
